# Is it possible to export firebase cloud firestore data to a postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am prototyping a mobile app and i want to make it quickly. Nothing faster than using firebase real time database or firebase cloud firestore.

However, i plan to migrate to a postgresql database after the end of the beta test. But i don't want to lose the existing data already stored in firebase. Are there some possibilities to export my firebase noSQL data to a postgreSQL database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could certainly write code that reads all of the data from Cloud Firestore and writes it into a PostgreSQL database, but this would be completely application-specific work. There is no generic way to do this, and since Cloud Firestore is schemaless, there is effectively no way to automate it in a general-purpose way.

Comment: On a side note, why not just stick with Cloud Firestore for production? :)

Comment: Thanks. It might be a possibility but i will need to process complex queries to retrieve my data. Hard to make it with firestore. Only an SQL can be accurate for such operations.